# help me to get started with .net?

Tags: .net

I am new to .net and i dont know even bits and pieces of .net can any one say me what are all the requirements for doing my first application in .net any help will be appreciable ..waiting for the reply

Comment: Do you have any other programming experience? What languages? Why do you want ot learn .NET? Do you want to program websites with ASP? Make Windows GUI applications? Write command line tools? Use Silverlight? What you want to do will vary the information you need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting started with .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387181/getting-started-with-net)

Comment: Maybe we could help better if you tell us a little about your background programming experience

Comment: @Wayne werner i have 8 months experience in php

Comment: @Claudio Redi:
     i have worked in php for past 8 months and did two projects but .net is very new to me

Answer (score 4):

As for the toolchain, a good way to get started is to download and install Microsoft's free [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Windows/).

Answer (score 2):

Go buy one of the [Murach](http://www.murach.com) books on .NET.

Copy down each example and build each example.  Get your muscle memory going.

I'd highly recommend learning C#, since you will most likely make more money and have more job opportunities with it.

Download an open source project like Dot Net Nuke, or BlogEngine.NET.

Set a breakpoint on page_load and build.  STep through the entire site, and see the code.

Answer (score 2):

Are you new to programming in general or just .NET? If you are familiar with programming in general (C/C++, Java, etc) then you should have no problem jumping into .NET, especially C# as you will find the syntax very familiar, and can probably transfer source code you already have over directly.

If you are completely new you can try googling [C# tutorials](http://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+tutorials&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) (replace C# with VB, or F#, or whatever your favorite implementation is) to get a large list of good tutorials. You can also get good help from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com), [CodeProject](http://codeproject.com), [CodePlex](http://Codeplex.com) and get most of your questions answered here as well.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It's a big area: [.NET Framework Learning Topics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663309.aspx)

Define your requirements to narrow down the appropriate technologies.

Answer (score 1):

Start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/beginner/default.aspx

There are resources no matter what your current skill level.  (Don't be afraid to try the Kids Corner if you're REALLY new to programming.)

Also, it's a very good idea to find a mentor.

And if you're going to go with books, my personal preference is the WROX series.  Less error-prone than others, easier to uunderstand.  They just "gety it right."

Answer (score 1):

Basically.  Get moving :) nothing is going to teach you more than just getting started....
Download Studio Express.  http://www.microsoft.com/express/Windows/  This will allow you to start coding.. Just Create your first page.  and start putting code in the code behind...